# JQuery - finding text not enclosed in tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a chrome extension that adds links to web pages based on matching certain regular expressions.  I am using JQuery to get all the text nodes from within the body tag as follows, and then match the regular expression and add a link if necessary:

```
$('*', 'body').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3
}).each(function() {
  regexMatchFn($(this), $(this).text());
});
```

So this works fine for text enclosed in tags within the body of an HTML page.  However, I'm testing against scenarios with pages where text is not enclosed in a tag and I'm not able to capture it using the aforementioned method.

Here's an example of the markup that's causing me trouble:

```
<body>
  text-not-captured
  <p>text-captured</p>
  <p>text-captured</p>
</body>
```

What would be the best way to capture the non-captured text in a scenario like this?

Comment: what does this do `$(this), $(this).text()` context as child of that context?

Comment: @guradio I'm passing the node and the content of the node to the regex matching function.

Comment: are you sure you are referring to the correct context in this scenario?

Comment: @guradio, when I'm stepping through the code in chrome dev tools it looks like it's the correct context.  It is entirely possible that I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, simply doing this:

```
$("body").text()
```

will get all the text inside of the body without the tags.

Be careful, though, as this also includes those inside `<script>` tags, which might be not what you want.

If you want to get everything aside from the script tags, you can do this instead:

```
var all = $("body").html();
console.log($($.parseHTML(all)).text());
```

Comment: "Be careful, though, as this also includes those inside <script> tags, which might be not what you want."


This is the primary reason that I'm not using this method, if I capture all the text within the body tag then I have to determine what's already been matched, what is effectively dis-allowed from being matched, etc.  Not the worst thing in the world, but still kind of a pain.

Comment: @morris295 I edited the post if you don't want the script tags.

Comment: This might mash all the text into one string.  If he wants to evaluate certain phrases of text, it wouldn't be as easy to do.  Otherwise, it's a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're looking for, is this what you had in mind?

I may be a little rusty on jQuery `add()`, but I think you need to get the contents for only the body element and then filter that for text nodes.  Afterwards you can `add` all other elements except script tags:

```js
$('body').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3 && this.wholeText.replace(/\s+/g, '') !== ''
}).add('body *:not(script)').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  text-not-captured
  <p>text-captured</p>
  <p>text-captured</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code uses a regex to select only text in the body tag. It doesn't include text inside script tags, and it doesn't include text in child elements. I'm not sure about all your code, but this should help.

```
// remove the scripts from the page  
$("body > script").remove();

// regex match only text in the body tag
var requiredText = document.body.innerHTML.match(/(\w+)(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)/igm);

console.dir(requiredText);
```

Example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mikeferrari/wrfwo5mu/